# Google Cast Custom Receiver CORS Header

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to build Google Cast custom receiver.

i tried the basic receiver example below to play youtube video, But i am getting CORS header issue.

```
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic
```

How can I set CORS header in CAF receiver, any suggestions

Comment: I suggest to follow the idea set by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#cors). `To setup your CORS headers, give your media server all the addresses of the servers where you host your receiver application, (development, staging, and external servers).`

Comment: I am trying to cast Youtube or Twitch live stream to chromecast which is external content.

I found that we need to setup CORS proxy server, not sure what is steps involved

Comment: Did any step cors proxy server for Chromecast, what is the easy solution without too much bandwidth costs.